# Passing an invalid URL to web page code

Tags: url, redirect, http-status-code-404

**I was wondering if the following is possible:**

If a visitor to a web site types an incorrect URL path wrong I'd like the invalid path to be displayed on the page.

**Example:** Visitor goes to *www.stackoverflow.com/made_up_domain_path*

I'd like the page they are taken to for any incorrect paths to display something like; *"I'm sorry 'made_up_domain_path' is not a valid page."*

I'm not sure if .htaccess can be used for this. I currently have the following in .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
```

Which redirects to a basic "page not found" page.

Is this something that can even be achieved?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using the following javascript:

`window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;`

This returned everything after the "/" in the URL.